# Applying colors to Spotfire Table Headers

Tags: tibco, spotfire

How do you apply custom colors to Spotfire Table/Cross Table Headers? I am only able to apply colors for the table cells but not for Table headers. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The only way I know to manipulate table headers is through the fonts portion which doesn't provide coloring as an option in either the UI or the API from what I can tell. If you don't get an answer on SO it might be worth asking TIBCO themselves @ [TIBCO Support](https://support.tibco.com/login.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only alternative I can imagine is using the Label rendering, and replace your text headers by images.
But you'll need to create an image for each possible value of your axis...

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the header and set the color using the menu:

[image: see attached image].

Answer (score -1):

Now you can add the custom color to the header part of the visualization by making

use of Spotfire 7.0

Regards
Manoj Singh

Comment: Really? Where us this configuration available?